# Passing a string slice, returning a string slice. But who owns it?

Tags: rust

I'm a beginner to Rust and just learning the ownership concept.

I'm using this function to reverse a String

```
fn reverse(input: &str) -> String {
    //we are receiving a borrowed value, 
    input
    //get an iterator of chars from the string slice
    .chars()
    //Goes between two iterators. 
    //From the doc:  double-ended iterator with the direction inverted.
    .rev()
    //collect into a String
    .collect::<String>()
}

fn process_reverse_case(input: &str, expected: &str) {
    assert_eq!(&reverse(input), expected)
}

fn main() {
    process_reverse_case("robot", "tobor");
}
```

I would like to understand who owns `robot` and `tobor`.

- I'm passing a borrowed value. Which is a string slice.
- I understand this can't be modified. So when we are *collecting* the reversed string, I think we are collecting it into a `argument 1` of `assert_eq!`. Am I right?
- But as the process of reversing + collection happens inside `reverse`, the memory needed keeps increasing. Does `argument 1` of `assert_eq!` account for that?
- The above question might have been solved by the compiler at compile time. Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your claims are mostly wrong, let me try to correct them.

> *Passing a string slice, returning a string slice*

`fn reverse(input: &str) -> String` you are accepting a [string slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html), but returning a [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html). A `String` *"has ownership over the contents of the string*".

---

> *I understand this [a string slice] can't be modified*

You can modify a `&mut str`, e.g.

```
fn to_lower(s: &mut str) {
    s.make_ascii_lowercase();
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = String::from("ABC");
    println!("{}", a);
    to_lower(&mut a);
    println!("{}", a);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=ccbf3668930609503144b9f8aad03f82))

---

> *So when we are collecting the reversed string, I think we are collecting it into a argument 1 of assert_eq!*

No. You collect it into a string, that is what `collect::<String>()` is for. Also your function `reverse` returns a `String`.
This means, that you are calling the function `reverse`, which returns a `String` and you are passing that `String` as the first "argument" to the `assert_eq!` macro.

---

> *the memory needed keeps increasing. Does argument 1 of assert_eq! account for that?*

No, how should it? That's all done inside of the `reverse` function. `assert_eq!` just takes two parameters. Where they come from is uncertain and not needed to know.

---

> `assert_eq!(&reverse(input), expected)`

What happens in this line is, that you are calling your `reverse` function with `input` as parameter. But normally you can't compare `&T` with `T` (a reference to *something* with an actual instance of *something*), that's where the `&` (ampersand) in front of `reverse` comes into play. `String` implements the [`Deref` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Deref) which means it can be seen as a `str` as well (see the [doc for Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)). But now you are trying to compare a `str` with `&str`, which does not work and that's why you put `&` in front, so you actually end up with `&str` and `&str` which you can [compare](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) with `==`.

---

> *I would like to understand who ownes `robot` and `tobor`.*

Nobody. In fact they live inside of the data section in the ELF/Binary itself. They don't have an owner per se, but can be used as `&str` wherever needed.